# Ubuntu 21.10 Cannot Print From WINE Application

Tags: wine, printing, cups-lpd

Since one of the recent Ubuntu updates, WINE applications will no longer print. There are no on-screen errors but nothing happens either when I send a document to the printer. I can print a test page through the Ubuntu printer settings panel and it prints well but fails to completely eject the page although that's possibly an unrelated issue. The printer is a USB HP Photosmart 7350 but the issue also happens on my other PCs with Ubuntu with Epson printers.

I also just printed a 2-sided document which took over thirty seconds to load the second side, then another half hour or so before it printed the three lines of text on it.

I found this in the error log:

```
E [05/Mar/2022:00:00:30 -0800] Unknown directive JobPrivateAccess on line 126 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [05/Mar/2022:00:00:30 -0800] Unknown directive JobPrivateValues on line 127 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [05/Mar/2022:00:00:30 -0800] Unknown directive SubscriptionPrivateAccess on line 128 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [05/Mar/2022:00:00:30 -0800] Unknown directive SubscriptionPrivateValues on line 129 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
W [05/Mar/2022:21:57:08 -0800] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'photosmart-7350-Gray..\' already exists
W [05/Mar/2022:21:57:08 -0800] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'photosmart-7350-RGB..\' already exists
```

Comment: Are you using Boomaga (virtual printer) or some other (physical) printer driver? Can you print on "PDF" (virtual) printer?

Comment: No, printing to a standard USB printer. I don't have a PDF printer installed.